# Out of Memory error on createbitmap

Tags: android, image

> ```
>                     BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>                     bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
>                     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Common.getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage,rootView.getContext()), bounds);
>                     BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>                     Common.setBitmap(null);
>                     Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Common.getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage, rootView.getContext()), opts);
>                     saveToInternalSorage(bm);
>                     ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(Common.getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage,rootView.getContext()));
>                     String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
>                     int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) :  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
>                     int rotationAngle = 0;
>                     if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) rotationAngle = 90;
>                     if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) rotationAngle = 180;
>                     if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) rotationAngle = 270;
>                     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
>                     matrix.postRotate(rotationAngle);
>                     try
>                     {                       
>                         Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
>                         bitmap2 = rotatedBitmap;//BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
>                     }
>                     catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
>                     {                       
>                     }
> ```

Basically at times, i get my image rotated. So I have implemented that function, the problem lies on createbitmap i get outofmemory error. I want to avoid that error , without modifying the size of the image... and the quality. i want to keep same size and quality.

Comment: You have to reduce the size of image,it will through out of memory exception else. Please explain when you are getting OutOfMemory error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use large heap, you should write in AndroidManifest.xml.

android:largeHeap="true"

If you want to check heap size on your device, call ActivityManager.getLargeMemoryClass().

ActivityManager am = ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
int largeMemory = am.getLargeMemoryClass();

Comment: where do u specify android:largeHeap="true" in the manifest, in the application tag?

Comment: In the manifest particular activity tag which you have used bitmap

Answer (score 0):

You have far bigger problems, such as the fact that your app will not work on most Android devices. [Use your `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) and get rid of `getRealPathFromURI()`.

That being said, there is no guarantee that you can allocate a bitmap of the size needed to rotate the image. Whether you can or not will be based on the state of your heap and the resolution of the image. Your choices are:

1. Switch to using native code via the NDK for the image rotation. This too is not guaranteed to work, but the odds are a lot higher, because you have all system RAM to work with.
2. Switch to using `android:largeHeap="true"`. This will have no effect on many devices. However, on some, it will increase your heap limit and make it somewhat more likely that your bitmap allocation will succeed.
3. Settle for resizing the image.
4. Tell the user "sorry, we do not have enough memory to rotate the image".